# I need to get some results as a result of some data that I send in Python

Tags: python

I need to get some results as a result of some data that I send.
I have 3 files:
1:" binary_search() that returns an average of(upper 0x70 and lower=0.20 bounds)"
2." dictionary that takes the average as a value of key "data": binary_search()"
3. "read_data file that sends the dictionary(as an opcode) and waits for the result:"
3.1 "if -1<result<1 exit(0) passed"
3.2 "if result>1 upper_bound will be now = average, the low bound still be 0x20 and try another time"
3.3 "if result < 1 upper_bound still be 0x70  and lower = average..."
Thanks

file 1:

```
def binarySearch(lower_bound,  upper_bound):
    avg = (upper_bound + lower_bound) // 2
    print(avg)
    return avg
```

file 2

```
self.MxFEAxiRegMsg = {
        "opcode": self.iCD.MICROBLAZE_REGFILE_SET,
        "cmd": self.iCD.SPI_WRITE,
        "addr": 0x71,
        "data": sample.binarySearch()
```

file 3

```
 is_not_sync = True
while is_not_sync:
    rcvD.send_the_message("MxFEAxiRegMsg", rcvD.all_strck.MxFEAxiRegMsg)
    time.sleep(2)
    fm.rcv_the_packets(wait_for_optcode=38)
    fm.rcv_the_packets(wait_for_optcode=90)
    if -1 < modem_snr < 1 and modem_sync != 0 and modem_freq < 1000 and sent_pack == receive_pack :
        print(modem_snr)
        print(modem_sync)
        print(modem_freq)
        print(sent_pack, receive_pack)
        is_not_sync = False

    elif modem_snr > 1:
            binarySearch(upper_bound=binarySearch, lower_bound=0x20)
            # res = fm.rcv_the_packets(wait_for_optcode=38)
            # res_2 = fm.rcv_the_packets(wait_for_optcode=90)

    elif modem_snr < -1:
            binarySearch(upper_bound=0x70, lower_bound=binarySearch)
            # res = fm.rcv_the_packets(wait_for_optcode=38)
            # res_2 = fm.rcv_the_packets(wait_for_optcode=90)


print(f" modem_snr: {modem_snr}\n modem_freq: {modem_freq}\n modem_sync: {modem_sync}\n "
      f"sent_packets: {sent_pack}\n receive_packets: {receive_pack}\n Test Passed")
```

Comment: could you post your code? also your question is not clear, could you make an specific question about your code?

Comment: Hi,   I calculate avg in file 1 as I have limits(upper and lower) I take the answer to the second file to key "data" then I send the whole dictionary as an opcode(file 3) and wait for a response(modem_snr), now the mess is starting for me if the answer was bigger than 1 or smaller than -1 I need to fix my upper or lower limit in the first file and change it to the average number that al; ready sent...and continue with this loop till I get my result in limits.

Answer (score 0):

please use “`” to start the code and end the code, :D

like : `testing123 testing`

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer ;)

Comment: sorry, i cannot post any commenus on others post or questoon, because i dont have 125 reputation, so i cannot post it ;-;